# Minus operator in Linq

Tags: sql-server, linq

I am trying to get a result of a query which is like A - (b join c). Below is the sql expression , I want the linq expression of it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
select distinct ch_mst_key from dim_channel MINUS
select distinct ch.channel_key 
from xref_ch_grp_det ch, xref_ch_grp_mst chg 
where chg.ch_grp_type_key = 3 and chg.src_func_key = 5
```

Comment: Is it valid TSQL statement? If you find correct TSQL operator, you'll find correct Linq expression as well.

Comment: yes , I am getting records while running this sql query. Just want the linq expression of it.

Comment: you can look into Except operator of LINQ

Comment: I was looking into it.. but not able to make a correct a linq expression of it. would appreciate if you help me in making that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var differenceTable = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable());
```

Put the result of select query before MINUS in dt1 and put the result of select query after MINUS in dt2 and then use the above query.

Comment: what would be the return type of my action method in that case as the result is stored in a var.

Comment: IEnumerable<DataRow> would be the return type

Comment: Getting error - Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<char>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Nishchal\Source\RDMBarc\RDMBarc\Repositories\MappingChannelToGroupRepository.cs 90 20 RDMBarc

Comment: While returning the result i.e. -  var difference = query1.AsEnumerable().Except(query2.AsEnumerable());

            return difference;

Comment: didn't you use datatables as given in my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111424/discussion-between-n2j-and-akshey-bhat).

Comment: I changed the return type of my action method to IEnumerable<DataRow>

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LINQ [`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as follow :

```
var query =
        (from dc in dim_channel select dc.ch_mst_key)
        .Except
        (
            (from ch in xref_ch_grp_det ch
             from chg in xref_ch_grp_mst
             where chg.ch_grp_type_key = 3 && chg.src_func_key = 5
             select ch.channel_key
            ).Disinct()
        ).Disinct();
```

Comment: I used your query , I made some changes in it , as I replaced dc.ch_mst_key with dc.CHANNEL_DISPLAY_NAME , I am getting error after the except keyword that -  System.linq>iQueryable<string> does not contain a defination for Except and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>,System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Are `CHANNEL_DISPLAY_NAME` and `channel_key` have the same datatype? Source data and `Except()` parameter must be compatible types

Comment: No Channel_display_name is of varchar type whereas Channel_mst_key is of number type.

Comment: You need to convert one to match type of the other